# Issue with making terminal

Tags: vb.net

I am coding a terminal in VB.net, And when I type in 'help' and press enter, Nothing happens. It is supposed to show 'This is the only command. :P'.

I appear to not be more specific so let me explain what happened.

I put in the code below, I executed the application and then I typed in 'help' and then I hit the enter key then nothing happened at ALL.

Here is the entire code:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyPress
    Dim lines = RichTextBox1.Lines
    Dim num = lines
    Dim textlength = RichTextBox1.TextLength

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        If num.Last.ToString() = "help" Then
            RichTextBox1.AppendText("This is the only command. :P\r\n")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you used the debugging tools in Visual Studio to set breakpoints and step through your code line by line to see what's it doing?

Comment: Cory, I need a fixed code. I simply do not know how to fix this. Read the code again then you would understand.

Comment: I understand the code. There isn't anything that stands out to me as wrong. Put a breakpoint on the first line of that method and start the debugger in Visual Studio. When you press a key, your program should pause on that first line. Then you can inspect the values of your variables to see what's happening and find where the logical errors are.  If you've never used a debugger to inspect your code while its running, now is a great time to learn. You can learn to solve this on your own and that's all I'm trying to help you to do.

Comment: No, you don't understand the code. This is pure broken. It does absolutely nothing at ALL. It is susposed to add a new line saying 'This is the only command. :P' when I press the enter key.

Comment: You aren't going to get any help acting like that,

Comment: Does it compile? Does your event handler fire? What are the values of `lines`, `num`, `textlength`, `e.KeyChar`, `num.Last` when you run your code? If you can't answer these questions, neither can we. You need to step through your code using the debugging tools in Visual Studio and inspect those variables. Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6q0_HGfXMQ

Comment: Well, I am trying to get help to fix the code, **Bradley Uffner**. I wasn't even acting "very mean".

Comment: The problem is, your code (what there is of it) doesn't appear wrong, but we're having to make assumptions like is `lines` an `IEnumerable<String>` or perhaps a `List<String>`? If so, you don't need the `ToString()` call. If not, maybe it's a problem with the conversion to string from some other type, etc, etc, etc... The _only_ way to diagnose the problem from that snippet is to step through the code and identify what's not working. We can't do that for you. @Cᴏʀʏ is attempting to walk you through the process of debugging your code.

Comment: Well, Try out the code and see it for yourself and you will KNOW what is not working. So actually, The code does appear wrong. And it needs fixed.

Comment: By the way, I can't debug because I don't know how to because I use Visual Studio Community 2015 and the video @Cᴏʀʏ is Visual Studio 2010 (I think so)

Comment: @FrizeioOfficial: The point I'm trying to make is that it's *your* job to run the code and find out what's not working. Then come here and ask a question if you haven't fixed it yourself after debugging. If you inspect the value of `num.Last()`, you might find that it doesn't exactly equal "help", which is why your code appears to not do anything.

Comment: @FrizeioOfficial: You can absolutely debug code in the community edition. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986851.aspx

Comment: "And it needs fixed."... Sorry, I don't work for you. I'm happy to offer advice to someone who's willing to try and help themselves, but I'm not here to do your work for you. FWIW My guess is that the line has a carriage return at the end, so the last line will be `help\n`, but you'd need to use the debugger to find out. (And yes, every version of Visual Studio going all the way back to VB2 has debugging support built in). Just select the line at the top of the method and add a breakpoint (F9 if I remember for the VB key layouts), then run the program

Comment: Oh, right. And can you replace `num.Last.ToString()` to the code for the second last line please?

Comment: Turns out @Cᴏʀʏ was right... Last line is blank after keypress...

Comment: Yup. Now I found the problem and I need the code for "second last line". I tried `num.Last-1.ToString()` but it generated an exception. Any ideas?

Comment: @FrizeioOfficial See my answer. Use LINQ... `RichTextBox1.Lines.Reverse.Skip(1).First()` or you could do... `RichTextBox1.Lines(RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 2)` but I find the former much more readable

Comment: The issue was resolved. I have a different question now. Check the main question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, having attached a debugger to your code, it was instantly obvious what the problem is... When you get to the comparison, `lines.Last()` is an empty string.

There are a number of ways to get the 2nd to last line. I prefer LINQ, so here's your code tidied up, using a case and culture-insensitive string comparison (so you can type `Help` too)...

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        If String.Equals(RichTextBox1.Lines.Reverse.Skip(1).First(),
                         "help",
                         StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format("This is the only command. :P{0}", Environment.NewLine))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I've also used `Environment.NewLine` to make your code more portable, and `String.Format()` to combine the strings in a way that doesn't eat memory for no reason. It's overkill for this example but it shows how it should be done.

It's worth noting that using a debugger is a crucial skill for any developer (well, ok, there is an alternative which is extensive logging, but you need to know both). You will need this skill to solve any number of problems.

In case you're not familiar with the concept, debugging is like pausing your program and letting you examine what's going on, then run a single command at a time to see what the program is doing.

Comment: The issue was resolved. I have a different question now. Check the main question body.

Comment: Please don't do that. If this issue is resolved, accept an answer and then ask a new question. The point of SO is to become a repository for all programming questions/answers. What you're doing is preventing anyone who had the same problem as you finding the answer. I've reverted your edit

Comment: (But feel free to put a link to your new question here so we can find it)

Comment: Well, I have another problem. How can you make it so if the backspace key is pressed, It does nothing?

Comment: Let's take a step back here... You're trying to use the RTF as a console and that's not what it's designed for. There are going to be a hundred other things that don't work the way you want (Pasting, Select All/Delete, using Right-To-Left unicode characters, etc) all of which will mess up your "history". If I were you, I'd have a single plain textbox for input. When the user presses Enter, do your processing and then push the output to the "console" RTF which you can set to ReadOnly. Better yet, use an actual console application. It's what they're there for...

Comment: If you _really_ want to do it this way, make your own control that inherits from RichTextBox. That will give you the level of control you need (and keep all the code associated with managing the RTF in a class for that specific purpose).  As it is, your Form is going to get cluttered with a lot of RTF-specific code, meaning that if you want to create another one somewhere else, you're going to have to unpick that code, duplicate it and then maintain two identical sets of code.

Comment: Or, failing all of the above... Be lazy and use someone else's code. Eg http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14908/Command-Prompt-Control

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but I noticed that you are writing your code to create a new line incorrectly

You did this:

```
RichTextBox1.AppendText("This is the only command. :P\r\n")
```

While it should be something like this:

```
RichTextBox1.AppendText("This is the only command. :P" & vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Don't use `vbCrLf`... It's not portable. Get into the habit of using `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: The issue was resolved. I have a different question now. Check the main question body.

Answer (score 0):

By trying your code and removing the

```
 If num.Last.ToString() = "help" Then
 End If
```

And putting this line of code

```
 If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then

        RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "This text will appear on the next line.")

    End If
```

It works fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue was resolved. I have a different question now. Check the main question body.